# Is there a way to trigger "back" on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using React Native with `react-native-navigation`. My task is to implement a customized "back" button that behave the same way as device's "back". Googling returns `BackHandler`, which is not the case.

Is there a way that we can trigger "back" with React Native?

Answer (score 0):

In react-navigation v5 we have navigation.goBack()

more info [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#goback)

e.g.

```
 onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the question is about `react-native-navigation`. Anyway we will think about migrating from `react-native-navigation` to `react-navigation` too

Comment: have you tried this https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/api/stack/#pop